# how to simulate multiple socket in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, debugging, sockets, client-server

Hi I am developing an Android client-server based app with multiple client app connecting to the server app. I am using socket to communicate between the clients and server. I want to simulate multiple clients and a server and debug the communication between them. How do I simulate multiple clients and sever communicating in the emulation mode. If I have to do the same with mobiles, I would need several mobiles which I dont have at the moment. And unless I am sure of the functionality and performance of the app, I dont want to invest on multiple mobiles. So, I am looking for a way to develop and debug the functionality  in the emulation mode.

Comment: The server will running on Android and the client could be on any device be it tablet, PC, phone etc?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. You could use low level networking tools ( ex. netcat ) to connect to your server and have 1 android emulator running, but multiple clients connected to the server.
2. I would recommend writing your code for android in a way that allows you to make your own java client application that interacts with the same server.  You can easily run multiple instances of the same java client on a desktop / laptop, while an Android emulator  is rather taxing for a computer ( multiple emulators probably isn't a good idea ).  Reusable code is a good thing, making the "communication" code as it's own java library can help you later on in the future, and is just good software engineering.

If you are going to be simulating this often and the client-server interaction is pretty frequent you should probably go with option 2. If the interaction is really simple than 1 may work for you.